# Convert seconds to minutes

Tags: r, lubridate

I am new to R, please help me to understand the conversion from seconds to minutes.

I'm doing a travel time analysis, and I get the result in seconds, which is not convenient for descriptive analysis and subsequent visualizations. There are a lot of calculations in different time sections, here is a small piece:

```
trip_stats <- cyclistic_df %>%
  group_by(member_casual) %>% 
  summarise(average_ride_length = round((mean(ride_length), 2),  # average ride length (total ride time / trips)
            median_ride_length = round(median(ride_length), 2),  # median ride length
            min_ride_length = round(min(ride_length), 2),  # minimum ride length
            max_ride_length = round(max(ride_length), 2))  # maximum ride length
head(trip_stats)
```

Conclusion:

```
# A tibble: 2 × 5
  member_casual average_ride_length median_ride_length min_ride_length max_ride_length
  <chr>         <drtn>              <drtn>             <drtn>          <drtn>         
1 casual        22.72 secs          785 secs           1 secs          1922127 secs   
2 member        12.19 secs          525 secs           1 secs            89872 secs
```

Or here's another example:

```
# Average ride length (ride_length):
ride_lengt_avg <- round(mean(cyclistic_df$ride_length), 2)
print(ride_lengt_avg)
```

Conclusion:

```
Time difference of 977.28 secs
```

I tried different variants with as_hms, format "%M:%S", minutes(), but unfortunately it still outputs the results of calculations in seconds. For example, I have created a number of columns, among which there is a column with only hour:

```
# Format time as HH:MM:SS:
cyclistic_df$time <- format(as.Date(cyclistic_df$date), "%H:%M:%S")

# Create new column for time:
cyclistic_df$time <- as_hms((cyclistic_df$started_at))

# Create new column for hour:
cyclistic_df$hour <- hour(cyclistic_df$time)
```

Conclusion:

```
0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12     13     14     15     16     17
  casual  32053  20813  12246   6763   4515   8707  23390  40346  55066  56190  72233  93437 109905 114531 121187 134839 153614 170534
  member  25582  15645   8736   5268   6097  26049  81660 151664 180585 120035 109540 129717 149403 147804 148800 183330 249039 297724
        
             18     19     20     21     22     23
  casual 148452 111916  81388  69348  61476  44808
  member 233303 165938 115161  88668  65505  41332
```

Unfortunately by analogy I can't represent the output in minutes instead of seconds.

Dividing by 60 also doesn't help, and is only misleading because "secs" is retained.

I have added the following columns:

```
# Default format is yyyy-mm-dd, use start date:
cyclistic_df$date <- as.Date(cyclistic_df$started_at)  # the default format is yyyy-mm-dd

# Create column for year:
cyclistic_df$year <- format(as.Date(cyclistic_df$date), "%Y")

# Create column for month:
cyclistic_df$month <- format(as.Date(cyclistic_df$date), "%m")

# Create column for day:
cyclistic_df$day <- format(as.Date(cyclistic_df$date), "%d")

# Calculate the day of the week:
cyclistic_df$day_of_week <- wday(cyclistic_df$started_at)

# Create column for day of week:
cyclistic_df$day_of_week <- format(as.Date(cyclistic_df$date), "%A")  # wday(cyclistic_df$started_at, label = T, abbr = T)

# Format time as HH:MM:SS:
cyclistic_df$time <- format(as.Date(cyclistic_df$date), "%H:%M:%S")

# Create new column for time:
cyclistic_df$time <- as_hms((cyclistic_df$started_at))

# Create new column for hour:
cyclistic_df$hour <- hour(cyclistic_df$time)

# Calculate & Create ride length column by subtracting ended_at time from started_at time and converted it to minutes:
cyclistic_df$ride_length <- as_hms(difftime(cyclistic_df$ended_at, cyclistic_df$started_at))
```

If I understand correctly, then the columns year, month, day, hour, ride length can be created with numeric type at once, so that later you don't have to convert them to numeric every time.
It is better not to use format( , "%__"), right?

I would be grateful for your help!

Comment: So just take the output and divide the 'seconds' data by 60.  What is your real question here?

Answer (score 5):

`as.numeric` accepts `units=`:

```r
set.seed(42)
d <- (Sys.time()) - (Sys.time() - runif(10, 0, 99))
d
# Time differences in secs
#  [1] 90.56578 92.77045 28.32780 82.21430 63.53279 51.39048 72.92223 13.33198 65.04222 69.80140
as.numeric(d, units = "mins")
#  [1] 1.5094297 1.5461741 0.4721299 1.3702383 1.0588798 0.8565080 1.2153704 0.2221996 1.0840370 1.1633566
```

You might be able to apply this to all of those columns with something like this (assuming `dplyr`):

```r
trip_stats <- trip_stats %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("_length"), ~ as.numeric(., units = "mins")))
```

or a little more generally with

```r
trip_stats <- trip_stats %>%
  mutate(across(where(~ inherits(., "difftime")), ~ as.numeric(., units = "mins")))
```

If base R, you can do something like:

```r
isdifftm <- sapply(trip_stats, inherits, "difftime")
trip_stats[,isdifftm] <- lapply(trip_stats[,isdifftm,drop=FALSE], as.numeric, units = "mins")
```

---

**EDIT**

Perhaps this is complete?

```r
trip_stats <- cyclistic_df %>%
  group_by(member_casual) %>% 
  summarize(across(disp, .names = "{.fn}", list(
    average_ride_length = mean,
    median_ride_length = median,
    min_ride_length = min,
    max_ride_length = max))) %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("_length"), ~ round(as.numeric(., units = "mins"), 2)))
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that it is more appropriate to set the type of column numeric when creating it? What is the correct way to change, for example, this:


```# Format time as HH:MM:SS:
cyclistic_df$time <- format(as.Date(cyclistic_df$date), "%H:%M:%S")

# Create new column for time:
cyclistic_df$time <- as_hms((cyclistic_df$started_at))

# Create new column for hour:
cyclistic_df$hour <- hour(cyclistic_df$time)```

Or should I change the type of columns after they are created?

Comment: (1) `format(..)` always returns a string, if you intend to do any math with it later then do not use `format`. (2) I don't know why you'd use `as.Date` ... if it is unambiguously a date (e.g., `"%Y-%m-%d"`), then you are not going to get HMS from it. (3) Instead of attempting to complicate that portion of your code, I suggest that your current code using `mean(ride_length)` and `median` and others can be wrapped with `as.numeric(., units="mins")` to get the same benefit. (I realize my code does it after `round`, which may not be desired.)

Comment: @prolabrus see my edit for the last code block

Comment: I have added the following columns:
`# Default format is yyyy-mm-dd, use start date:
cyclistic_df$date <- as.Date(cyclistic_df$started_at)  # the default format is yyyy-mm-dd

# Create column for year:
cyclistic_df$year <- format(as.Date(cyclistic_df$date), "%Y")

# Create column for month:
cyclistic_df$month <- format(as.Date(cyclistic_df$date), "%m")

# Create column for day:
cyclistic_df$day <- format(as.Date(cyclistic_df$date), "%d")`

Comment: `# Calculate the day of the week:
cyclistic_df$day_of_week <- wday(cyclistic_df$started_at)

# Create column for day of week:
cyclistic_df$day_of_week <- format(as.Date(cyclistic_df$date), "%A")  # wday(cyclistic_df$started_at, label = T, abbr = T)

# Format time as HH:MM:SS:
cyclistic_df$time <- format(as.Date(cyclistic_df$date), "%H:%M:%S")

# Create new column for time:
cyclistic_df$time <- as_hms((cyclistic_df$started_at))

# Create new column for hour:
cyclistic_df$hour <- hour(cyclistic_df$time)`

Comment: `# Calculate & Create ride length column by subtracting ended_at time from started_at time and converted it to minutes:
cyclistic_df$ride_length <- as_hms(difftime(cyclistic_df$ended_at, cyclistic_df$started_at))
`

If I understand correctly, then the columns year, month, day, hour, ride length can be created with numeric type at once, so that later you don't have to convert them to numeric every time.
It is better not to use format( , "%__"), right?

Comment: Oh, and please tell me how to insert a block of code in a comment, not just highlight it - I haven't figured it out.

Comment: comments are bad for code, typically better to edit the OP

Comment: I don't think I understand. One of your first comments is *"it is more appropriate to set the type of column number when creating it"*, suggesting you want an efficient process, but then you suggest code that has `format`x5, `wday`, `hour`, and `as_hms`x2, hoping to come to the same result of "numbers in minutes instead of seconds". If my suggested code does not work, please edit your question and add sample data, then provide expected output given that sample data, and perhaps it'll be more clear to me why you need to go through those extra steps.